# XML how do i get the imageView fixed to a position in a Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have two rows positioned vertically. Both rows contain a location icon with some text after it and I have the textview maxlength sets to 8.

I don't have problem when the text size is more than 8 because the location icon is positioned well, but when the text size is less than 8, the position of the location icon shift to the right. How can i make it fixed?

All I want is getting the location icon of the second row be at the same position as the first and then the text should follow.

Note: I don't want to use paddingRight to achieve this because i intend to use this layout in a list view where i won't know the minimum text length.

The image of the layout has been added, the XML is long, just look at the line on the image, you'll understand.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/copyboder4_two"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/most_lodged_number"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="77"
                    android:textSize="11sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_header"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="The Swtich at the LR is faulty, come and fix as  possible"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingRight="20dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/list_detail"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="I can perceive that the switch is vertyy.. " />



                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/most_complaints_expand"
                            android:layout_width="16dp"
                            android:layout_height="14dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_expand_more_black_18dp"
                            android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="42dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="16dp"
                android:layout_height="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icons8_manager48" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lecturer_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="20"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="16dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icons8_student_male_48"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/student_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="25"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="16dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icons8_marker_40"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/location_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Mass Comm Lab"
                android:maxLength="8"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/copyboder4_two"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/most_lodged_number2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="77"
                    android:textSize="11sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_header1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="The Swtich at the LR is faulty, come and fix as  
                 possible"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingRight="20dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/list_detail2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="I can perceive that the switch is vertyy.. 
                                 "/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/most_complaints_expand2"
                        android:layout_width="16dp"
                        android:layout_height="14dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_expand_more_black_18dp"
                        android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="42dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="16dp"
                android:layout_height="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icons8_manager48" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lecturer_number1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="20"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="16dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icons8_student_male_48"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/student_number1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="25"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="16dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icons8_marker_40"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/location_text1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lab 1"
                android:maxLength="8"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest you move from LinearLayouts to ConstraintLayouts. 
They will give you a cleaner solution (no nested layouts!), but they also come with Guidelines, that is what you need. Take a look here: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/#constrain-to-a-guideline

Comment: why is the maxlength 8 and the one at the top is 10

Comment: @kuti gbolahan that's a mistake, both should be 8, fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set a fixed layout_width for the two Textviews, another option is to add " " spaces to complete the text for each textview

Answer (score 1):

Quite honestly, your layout is a bit of a mess and more complicated than it needs to be.  So, it's hard to determine exactly how to get what you want.  Having said that, I believe if you add `android:layout_weight="1"`and `android:layout_width="0"`
to those TextViews it might point you in the correct direction.  You also probably need to add an empty `View` of the width you want to indent at the beginning of the horizontal line.

Comment: i had a typo.  fixed.

Comment: yeah, i'm new to android. Your comment helped, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the minimum ems of your "location_text" textview in the xml like below:

```
android:minEms="8"
```